Running a thread makes the interface (customtkinter) very slow
I'm writing my final project In python which is an system for driving teachers and student.
In the main function of the client, I'm running two threads: one related to communication with the server and the other related to the GUI. Once you are connected to the system, you can send messages to your teacher. In order to receive messages, I'm running another thread that starts just when the chat is activated.
the main func:
if __name__=="__main__":
    client = socket.socket()
    hostname = socket.gethostname()
    ip_adress = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)
    while(True):
        try:
            client.connect((ip_adress, 1729))
            break
        except:
            messagebox.showerror('error', ' communication failed')


    msg_send = []
    msg_recieve=[]
    locker=threading.Lock()

    socket_thread=threading.Thread(target=client_socket, args=(client,msg_send,locker,msg_recieve))
    gui_thread=threading.Thread(target=lambda : login_gui(msg_send,msg_recieve))
    socket_thread.start()
    gui_thread.start()
    socket_thread.join()
    gui_thread.join()

**
the chat function:
**
def chat(root, frame, id, msg_send, msg_recieve):
    def send_message(recipient_id,content,messages_frame):
        def print_msg(content):
            f = customtkinter.CTkFrame(messages_frame, width=480, height=30)
            f.pack()
            customtkinter.CTkLabel(f, font=('Century Gothic', 15),fg_color="dark green", text=content,corner_radius=6,width=56).place(x=400)


        if content.strip():
            message = Message.Message(content, id)
            message.set_recipient_id(recipient_id)
            msg_send.append(message)
            print_msg(content)

    def receiving_messages(event,chat_id,messages_frame):
        def print_msg(content):
            f = customtkinter.CTkFrame(messages_frame, width=480, height=30)
            f.pack()
            customtkinter.CTkLabel(f, font=('Century Gothic', 15),fg_color='gray31', text=content,corner_radius=6).place(x=2)

        while True:
            i = 0
            while i < len(msg_recieve):
                if event.is_set():
                    break
                try:
                    if msg_recieve[i].get_class_code() == 1:
                        if msg_recieve[i].get_sender_id()==chat_id:
                            content = msg_recieve[i].get_text()
                            print_msg(content)
                        del msg_recieve[i]
                    else:
                        i += 1
                except Exception as e:
                    print("Error1:", e)
            if event.is_set():
                break**

    def close_chat(root, frame, id, msg_send, msg_recieve, event):
        event.set()
        msg_send.append(f"disconnect:{id}")
        main(root, frame, id, msg_send, msg_recieve)

    def build_chat(data,chat_frame,event):

        clear_frame(chat_frame)
        msg_send.append(f"disconnect:{id}")
        messages_frame = customtkinter.CTkScrollableFrame(chat_frame, height=520, width=480,
                                                          label_text="Message "+data[0],
                                                          label_font=('Century Gothic', 25))
        messages_frame.place(y=0, x=0)

        msg_send.append(f"get:messages:{id}:{data[1]}")
        server_respond = False
        while not server_respond:
            i = 0
            while not server_respond and i < len(msg_recieve):
                try:
                    if msg_recieve[i].get_class_code() == 6:
                        list = msg_recieve[i].get_messages()
                        server_respond = True
                        del msg_recieve[i]
                    else:
                        i += 1
                except Exception as e:
                    print("Error:", e)
        for i in list:
            print(i.get_time())
            f = customtkinter.CTkFrame(messages_frame, width=480, height=30)
            f.pack()
            if i.get_sender_id()==id:
                    customtkinter.CTkLabel(f, font=('Century Gothic', 15), fg_color="dark green", text=i.get_text(),
                                           corner_radius=6, width=56).place(x=400)
            else:
                customtkinter.CTkLabel(f, font=('Century Gothic', 15), fg_color='gray31', text=i.get_text(),
                                       corner_radius=6).place(x=2)
        msg_send.append(f"connect:{id}")

        message_entry = customtkinter.CTkEntry(chat_frame, width=460, height=30, placeholder_text="message...",
                                               font=('Century Gothic', 20))
        message_entry.place(x=0, y=575)
        send_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(chat_frame, width=20, height=30, font=('Century Gothic', 20), corner_radius=6,
                                              text="➤",command=lambda :send_message(data[1],message_entry.get(),messages_frame))
        send_button.place(x=460, y=575)

        recieve_thread = threading.Thread(target=receiving_messages, args=(event,data[1],messages_frame))
       
        recieve_thread.start()

    event = threading.Event()
    clear_frame(frame)
    back_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=frame, width=120, text="back",
                                          font=('Century Gothic', 18), corner_radius=6, cursor='hand2',
                                          command=lambda: close_chat(root, frame, id, msg_send, msg_recieve, event))
    back_button.place(y=0, x=0)


    msg_send.append(f"get:students:{id}")
    server_respond = False
    while not server_respond:
        i = 0
        while not server_respond and i < len(msg_recieve):
            try:
                if msg_recieve[i].get_class_code() == 4:
                    list = msg_recieve[i].get_list()
                    server_respond = True
                    del msg_recieve[i]
                else:
                    i += 1
            except Exception as e:
                print("Error:", e)
    if list:
        chat_frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(frame, width=500, height=605)
        chat_frame.place(y=0, x=300)
        students_frame = customtkinter.CTkScrollableFrame(frame, height=520, width=200)
        students_frame.place(y=50, x=20)
        for student in list:
            customtkinter.CTkButton(master=students_frame,fg_color="royal blue",width=190, text=student[0], font=('Century Gothic', 20),corner_radius=1,command=lambda data=(student[0],student[1]): build_chat(data,chat_frame,event)).pack(pady=2)




The problem is that once the chat thread starts, the entire GUI interface becomes really slow. Everything is working, but it's noticeably slower. When I tried everything without this thread, it worked a lot quicker, so I know the thread is the problem, but I have to use it. I would appreciate suggestions on how to overcome this problem.

Why do you call the .join() on those threads? It is the cause of the issue because it will wait for the completion of those threads.

@acw1668 withount the join the  receive thread doenst work. I get this error: File "F:\StudentsApp.py", line 112, in chat
recieve_thread.start()
File "C:\Users\Li\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\threading.py", line 992, in start
_start_new_thread(self._bootstrap, ())
RuntimeError: can't create new thread at interpreter shutdown

It is not recommended (or should not) run the GUI in a child thread.  Run the GUI in main thread.

@acw1668 Do you have any ideas on how I can separate the received messages GUI from the child thread? because I need the messages to show on the screen immediately
